# GitHub Actions - Missing Environments settings menu for public repo under an organistaion

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

I'm looking to create a series of environments for my GitHub Actions to deploy to. According to documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment

`"Environments, environment protection rules, and environment secrets are available in public repositories for all products."`

My Repository is under an organistaion, and is public. I don't see the `Environments` menu under the settings page though?

Comment: Do you have admin permissions on the repo? See [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#creating-an-environment).

Comment: Yeah I'm an Admin on the repo and a full member of the Org the repo is in?

Comment: [This discussion](https://github.community/t/environment-settings-missing/154649/7) indicates that it's not available for private repos in non-enterprise organizations?

Comment: Notice that your docs link goes to GitHub AE, which isn't Free *or* Enterprise.

Comment: Oh woops, "is public"... definitely not my best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the organisation being on a "Legacy Platinum Plan", which is no longer offered and doesn't have this feature enabled.

The solution is to move to a Currently Offered plan which has that feature enabled.